# Two Intellij project windows that use different SDKs

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have two separate intellij projects, one that uses JDK 1.8 and another that uses JDK 11.0.14. I would like to have them both open side-by-side if possible. However, when I set the JAVA HOME variable in my path to either one of those, the IDE using the other SDK will not run.

I set the path manually in both IDEs, but they still don't run. I was wondering if it's possible to have two separate Intellij IDEs running that use different SDKs.

Comment: When you say "run", you mean run the tests / build the projects or something else (e.g. starting a tomcat and serving a web application through IntelliJ)?

Comment: I mean just having both projects open in separate windows to view their configuration files.

Comment: Normally IntelliJ supports one JDK per project (File / Project structure / SDKs, you can pick your own JDK home path for the project). If you say "it doesn't work", I guess you're doing something more than simply looking at the projects / running the tests / building the code?

Comment: I apologize, I should be more descriptive. I have the JDKs set for each project, but IDE seems to use whatever I have the JDK set as my JAVA_HOME environment variable. For example, when JAVA_HOME points to the 1.8 JDK, I get the following error when I try to build the IDE that uses JDK 11.0.14:

"Could not determine java version from '11.0.14'."

I am building the projects.

Comment: I can have both projects open, but I have to open one IDE, change the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the JDK of the other project, then open that project. I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve having to constantly change the environment variables.

Comment: What is your build tool (Maven, Gradle, other...)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245009/discussion-between-connor-d-and-matteo-nnz).

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible, if both or multiple JDK are installed in your system, each project can use a different SDK

go to File > Project Structure > Project SDK < and chose your preferred JDK from the drop-down menu

[image: Intiliji Project SDK]